# Persistent Storage Option for Standalone One-Off Angular Application

Tags: angular, database, typescript, angular5, storage

EDIT: How is this off-topic? I'm asking for a specific answer to a specific scenario.

I would like to mess around with some Angular (5+) applications. These are never going to leave my PC or go online or anything of the sort. The data maintained in the application should not be considered volatile and should persist as reliably as if the were being stored in a run-of-the-mill database (SQL or what-have-you). That is to say, I do not want to be tied to web browser storage (cookies, local/session storage, and so on).

Ideally, I would like to omit any sort of server-side portion of an Angular app. Just run `ng serve` and go, without worrying about any kind of server-side aspect to maintain/run/etc. Typescript is all I need.

So this boils down to my question: What are my Angular service classes going to talk to? I don't foresee the data being anything more complex than some POCOs which may have some relational mappings to one-another. Is there an Angular-only solution for storing these kinds of data? I would love to have my services interact with this persistent data store directly, as opposed to having to call some API. I'm open to just about any solution that could get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting dilemma...

My first thought is to set up a traditional database that can run locally using a container system, such as Docker.  You can set up a NodeJS app--or similar--to expose rest services to your data.

If that is too much overhead, I'd look into local file storage.  Since you want to be browser independent, you are a bit limited by browser APIs.  You should be able to load local files using Angular's HTTP Service and get requests.  Saving the files might be more complex, to do that without user interaction you'll probably want to use something like Electron or Cordova to deploy a desktop app.